# VirtualBox 32 bit registers in 64 bit host

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, 64bit, 32bit

I am using Kali Linux(64 bit) on VirtualBox for programming purposes. If Debugging with gdb, there are 64-bit Registers. Is it possible to use 32-bit Registers in 64-bit mode? Because I want to work with 32-bit Registers.

Comment: As this is a programming question, it's probably better suited to [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: If you're using an ancient book, add the `-m32` option to all the cc or gcc commands to force 32-bit mode.